# Turn the output of LoginGuard to false

Tags: angular

I would like to gain the user access to the /login page if a cookie has not been set yet but also gain them access to the page /search if the cookie has already been set.

**app-routing.modules.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] }
];
```

If the cookie has been set, the user has access to the page /search. In this case /search works, since LoginGuard returns true but /login doesn't work, since LoginGuard still returns true.

**login.guard.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import {SearchComponent} from '../search/search/search.component';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import {LoginService} from './login.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private searchComponent: SearchComponent, private cookieService: CookieService, private loginService: LoginService) {
  }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    return this.hasAccess();
  }

  hasAccess() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.loginService.hasCookie(this.cookieService.get('login')).subscribe(hasCookie => {
        if (hasCookie === 1) {
          return new Promise(() => {
            this.loginService.getCookie().subscribe(cookieFromServer => {
              if (cookieFromServer === this.cookieService.get('login')) {
                return resolve(true);
              } else {
                return resolve(false);
              }
            });
          });
        }
        return resolve(false);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

So the /search path is just the opposite of /login path. I have also tried it with `canActivate: [!LoginGuard]` and I have also created a new guard for login and added `!this.searchComponent.hasAccess();` as return but none of them worked for me.

Of course, I could use `router.navigate(['/']);` and that would work but the problem is that the page will be viewable for about 1 second and then the user will be redirected. This is exactly the reason why I am using a RouteGuard to prevent this issue and that works for the path /search. But I am just wondering how I could do the same for the path /login.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix my problem by adding `if (this.location.path() === '/login')` to the function `hasAccess()`. The if statement is added twice to reach the goal, so that /login gets the opposite purpose than /search.

```js
hasAccess() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.loginService.hasCookie(this.cookieService.get('login')).subscribe(hasCookie => {
      if (hasCookie === 1) {
        return new Promise(() => {
          this.loginService.getCookie().subscribe(cookieFromServer => {
            if (cookieFromServer === this.cookieService.get('login')) {
              console.log(this.location.path());
              if (this.location.path() === '/login') {
                return resolve(false);
              }
              return resolve(true);
            } else {
              return resolve(false);
            }
          });
        });
      }
      if (this.location.path() === '/login') {
        return resolve(true);
      }
      return resolve(false);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First recommendation, move the 'hasAccess' logic into the LoginGuard to remove dependency on the components.

From my understanding, you want to navigate to the search if the user is already logged in.  This should get you on the right track.  Hope it helps!

```
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private searchComponent: SearchComponent) {}
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.hasAccess() // The cookie will be handled here 
  }

  hasAccess(url: string): boolean {
    const hasValidCookie = cookieLogic();

    //if it has a valid cookie and you are on the login url then reroute to the search
    if ((hasValidCookie && url === '/login')) {
      this.router.navigate(['/search']);
      return true;
    }

    //if it's not the login page then simply return the value of your cookie logic
    return hasValidCookie;
  }

  private cookieLogic(): boolean() {
    //do your cookie logic and return a boolean value
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that out but the problem is that the component will be loaded and so the user will see the page for about 1 second and then they will be redirected. I would like to prevent this and that's why I am working with RouteGuard.

Comment: Per angular docs, the page itself should not be activated until the route guard completes.  With the code you have provided, the page should not be rendering.  Is there any async function inside your cookie logic?

Comment: Yes, there is even an async function inside an async function. I have updated my question, so you see the whole code.

Comment: `  return this.loginService.hasCookie(this.cookieService.get('login')).pipe(
    concatMap((hasCookie: boolean) => {
      if(hasCookie){
        return this.loginService.getCookie().map(cookieFromServer => {
          //might have to make this an observable i.e of()
          return cookieFromServer === this.cookieService.get('login');
        })
      }

      //might have to make this an observable i.e of(false)
      return false;

    }))`

Comment: Im not very good with promises so that was best attempt at an observable interpretation.  Anyhow, you dont want to actually do the subscriptions in there.  Since canactivate return an observable, our job is to provide it an observable and it will handle the subscription.  Let me know if that does you any good.

Comment: I could already fix that issue by adding `if (this.location.path() === '/login')` (see my answer). Thanks anyway for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect from the constructor of the view you are logging , for example

```
constructor(authService: AuthService, router: Router) {
    if (authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      router.navigate(['search']);
    }
  }
```

in the login constructor
and the opposite in the search constructor

Comment: I have tried that out but the problem is that the component will be loaded and so the user will see the page for about 1 second and then they will be redirected. I would like to prevent this and that's why I am working with RouteGuard.